# Can Regex handle nested operation?

Tags: regex, algorithm, nested

I have some string like:

`"1+""2*3"*4"+"5*6""`

and with some regexes, the answer should be:

`(1+((2*3)*4)+(5*6))`

can regex do this?

Comment: A clever puzzle. My first attempt has failed, but if sufficiently creative, one *should* be able to get this to work, shouldn't one? Maybe you need a BNF to get this to work but, at any rate, I shall be interested to see the solution when it appears.

Comment: Regular languages can not capture "recursive languages". This is a consequence of the *pumping lemma of regular expressions*. For example balancing brackets, etc. can not be solved with regular expressions. Some languages, like Perl, have extended the regular expression expresiveness slightly. That being said, if we know that the expression itself is *valid* (so no illegal input can be given), substituting can indeed be done.

Comment: I don't assume that my failed attempt will interest anyone, but, for information, in case someone cares, `s/((^|[-+*/"])[[:space:]]*)"([^"]*)"([[:space:]]*([-+*/"]|$))/\1\(\3\)\4/`. That's an extended-form regex, as for Sed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Interesting point. I had thought to try this with an external loop. I hadn't thought to make the regex itself recursive. That sounds hard.

Comment: @DanD. With a stack. Sure, but how does the machine know for which `"` *to push* and for which *to pop?* Would that not require a grammar? I look forward to your solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the input is **valid**, we can exploit some redundant constraints of such language to add the appropriate brackets. But this is actually more using "tricks". I really advice to use a more sophisticated tool, like a *push down automaton* (so a *parser*).

Well there is something here that we can spot: that is that if the next character is a number, or a sequence of double quote followed by a number, all other double quotes.

So we basically can do this with two regexes:

- the first one replaces all double quotes that are followed by zero or more double quotes followed by a number; and
- then replace all remaining double quotes (this is actually simply character replacement, so no regex necessary).

But this trick *only* works if the original input is valid. If it contains double quotes around operators, like `"+"`, then it can produce totally different results.

In Python, we can for example use:

```
from re import sub

def add_brackets(text):
    return sub(r'["](?=\"*[(\d])', '(', text).replace('"', ')')
```

This then gives us:

```
>>> add_brackets('"1+""2*3"*4"+"5*6""')
'(1+((2*3)*4)+(5*6))'
```

This here thus works because we only consider numbers and operators. If we would add variables, it would still work, but if we add more sophisticated elements like functions, then the problem becomes harder.

"Recursive languages" (well languages where certain element(s) *can* be defined in terms of itself) however are better parsed by tooling that is constructed for that, a [*push down automaton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push-down_automata).

The [*pumping lemma for regular languages*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) shows that languages like *(<sup>n</sup>)<sup>n</sup>* (a language that contains strings with a number of opening brackets, followed by the same number of closing brackets), can not be validated with regular expressions. The language you describe here is an example of that. So this regex is *not* capable of validating that. Some programming languages like *Perl* have extended regular expressions, such that these can validate *balancing brackets*. These are not regular expressions, at least not as defined by *Stephen Kleene*.